# Data table and Excel template

Tags: r, excel, data.table

I am trying to import data from Excel template into R. Below you can see how the table looks like:

[image]

This table contains titles (e.g 2021-2017 which is for Male and Female) for both columns and this causes problems when I try to import data into R. For uploading, I run the following lines of code:

```r
Export_I01 <- data.table(
    read.xlsx("Export_I01.xlsx", startRow = 2, endRow = 4, sheetIndex = 1, header = TRUE)
)
```

The output looks like the picture below:

[image]

This is not good input because there is a suffix: e.g `Male` is first column but also Third is `Male.1`. So can anybody help me to input this data in the same format as the table from Excel?

Comment: In R there are only column names, there are no names for group of columns. So you can't have a "*format which is same like table from Excel*" within R. For what purpose are you importing it into R?

Comment: Your data in Excel is really a range, not a table. Like R, Excel tables will not allow two columns with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do is but you can come up with some workarounds. This one uses `readxl`, `dplyr`, `zoo`, and `purrr`:

```
dt <- read_excel("test.xlsx", col_names = F)
dt <- dt %>% mutate(pmap_df(., ~ na.locf0(c(...))))
colnames(dt) <- gsub("\\.NA", "", paste(dt[1,], dt[2,], sep = "."))
dt <- dt %>% filter(row_number() > 2)
```

Which results in:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  English Country        `2021-2017.Male` `2021-2017.Female` `2016-2012.Male` `2016-2012.Female`
  <chr>   <chr>          <chr>            <chr>              <chr>            <chr>             
1 1       Czech Republic 5                55                 5                5                 
2 2       Denmark        5                0                  0                0
```

Answer (score 1):

R adds a suffix to differentiate columns with the same name. I'd suggest to change the names of the columns in excel to differentiate males and females by year, like "Male_2021_2017" and "Male_2016_2012".

You could also reformat the table to have only one "Male" and "Female" column, and add a "date" column where you specify the years that correspond to each value.

Comment: I can't change Excel template. So for that reason I trying to find some solution with R

Comment: Some of R's functions for reading tables/CSVs/spreadsheets have a `check.names=` (or similar) argument. This might produce a frame in R that has ambiguous column names, but one does not always need to change the *source* data to be able to avoid this auto-suffix behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a choice and that might depend on how flexible you are in changing the format of the excel file. If this is the way it must be formatted or is provided by you and not flexible you have to make a choice.

Choose between a wide or long format of your data.

Wide would mean you end up with 2 rows, with "Male_2021_2017" and "Male_2016_2012" as seperate columns (same for Female), while long would mean you end up with 4 rows with a new group column "year_range" and only having one column for Male and one for Female.

Either way is fine as there are several options to reshape in R between long and wide back and forth (melt/dcast)